# "Not equal" sign in Visual Prolog?

Tags: prolog, equals, clause, visual-prolog

I can't find any documentation on "not equal" sign in Visual Prolog. Please provide the right solution of this problem:

```
class predicates
        sister : (string Person, string Sister) nondeterm(o,o).
    clauses
        sister(Person, Sister) :-
            Person [not-equal-sign] Sister,
            parent(Person, Parent),
            parent(Sister, Parent),
            woman(Sister).
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I don't know what do you mean by "not equal" (does not unify?), but you could try these:

```
X \= Y
not(X = Y)
\+ (X = Y)
```

Comment: Are there differences between these options?

Comment: @alaboudi Apparently `\+` and `not` are better understood as "not provable" instead of "not equals". `\=`  or `=\=` are symbols for "not equals.
For example:
"It cannot be proved that 2 equals 4" is written as `\+ (2 =4)`
"2 does not equal 4" is written as `2 \= 4`
Source: http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/dictionaries/prolog/negation.html

Answer (score 9):

Documentation for the second variant pointed out by Kaarel can be found in [this Visual Prolog reference](http://wiki.visual-prolog.com/index.php?title=Language_Reference/Terms#Relational_Operators) page.

However the problem with your code goes a little deeper.  You need to wait for testing of non-equality until both terms Person and Sister are bound, so rearrange things like this:

```
    sister(Person, Sister) :-
        parent(Person, Parent),
        parent(Sister, Parent),
        not(Person = Sister),
        woman(Sister).
```

There is also syntax for an infix operator "<>" which means distinct (or different).  Once the two terms are bound this should give the same result as checking whether the terms cannot be unified, which is what the above construction does.