# How can i define different in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, visual-prolog

How can i define that two variables are not equal in Prolog? For example :

```
z is X and Y parent

X is male and Y is female
```

Now i want find sisters or brothers. But Prolog result is:

```
Y sister Y when parent have one child and not have X
```

Now i want define:

```
different(X,y).
```

I think old or other version of Visual Prolog have "different" in library but i dont find this in new Visual Prolog. What can i do?

Comment: Are you required to use Visual Prolog?

Comment: I suppose you're asking just for inequality operator:
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/7485430/925196][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7485430/925196

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8523825/772868

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define two variables are not equal in Prolog:

```
X \= Y
not(X = Y)
\+ (X = Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Equivalence** in Prolog is `==/2`. This is also defined between variables. It specifically does *not* unify two different variables as `=/2` would.

Some simple examples:

```
?- X = Y.
X = Y.
?- X == Y.
false.
```

And:

```
?- X = X.
true.
?- X == X.
true.
```

Since you specifically ask for **equality** between variables, I am wondering whether you are asking for something more than equivalence. Equality is sometimes defined as equivalence under substitution. So that `a = b` implies `f(..., a, ...) = f(..., b, ...)`.

In Prolog this seems to be the case as well:

```
?- f(a, B1, c) = f(a, B2, c).
B1 = B2.
?- f(a, B1, c) == f(a, B2, c).
false.
```

And:

```
?- f(a, B, c) = f(a, B, c).
true.
?- f(a, B, c) == f(a, B, c).
true.
```

Hope this helps!